# Error con Crystal Report No se ha podido cargar el informe

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

Actual mente el aplicativo esta funcionando para varios usuarios, pero aveces el sistema da error cuando tratan de ver la vista previa de un reporte que generan muchas veces al día.

El error que genera crytal report es **"No se ha podido cargar el informe"**, a nivel de Visual studio los reportes los he dejado como recurso incrustado y he ubicado en el app.config la etiqueta :

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
```

Según he investigado con eso deberian solventar la mayoria de error con crystal report pero ese error me sigue pasando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo general, eso depende de la versión del runtime de Crystal Report, puedes visitar el siguiente enlace para descargar la última versión
[Crystal report Runtime](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) 
En algunos casos se da también que el equipo del cliente no cuenta con los services pack adecuados para las aplicaciones NETFramework, haciendo necesaria su actualización.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que darle permisos al usuario a la carpeta de los temporales, en c:\windows\temp.
Cuandon crystal report carga los datos crea un temporal en la carpeta temp.